# How does shifting a binary number to the left translate to its hexadecimal representation?

Tags: binary, number-systems

So I have a binary output that is represented in Hex that I need to format it's binary representation in a certain way.

Say I have a binary output of: 000110111001 or  0x01B9 in HEX. I want to add 1 to the MSB of the output so that's like adding $2^{15}$ in decimal or 8000 in HEX.

And then I need to add either 00001 or 10001 at the END of the binary output at certain conditions. So what i'm planning to do is to left shift the output 5 times and then add the values 1 or 11 (in hex) to get my desired number. However, what i dont know is the equivalent of LEFT SHIFTING in binary in HEX.

Comment: It's not obvious what you are trying to do.  As a quick guess, I'd say you should convert the hex to binary, do the manipulations, and convert the result back to hex, but I suspect that isn't what you are really asking for.

Comment: What is the programming language that you use, what are the available operations? Is this to be solved on the level of processor-internal micro-code?

Comment: @RayButterworth I wanted to not do that solution and do this mathematically hopefully but im having trouble understanding the math

Comment: @LutzLehmann i'm doing this in C

Comment: You need to define what "I have" and "output" mean.  Is it printed on a piece of paper, or is it `long output=0x01B9;`, or `char *output="0x01B9";`, or what?

Comment: Sorry about that, it's the former

Comment: If $x$ is your input you seem to want $((x+0x8000) << 5) + (\operatorname{cond} ? 0x01 : 0x11)$ in hexadecimal or $((x+(1 << 15)) << 5) + (\operatorname{cond} ? 1 : (1 <<4)+1)$ in binary.

Comment: (the idea is to convert a hexadecimal string to an integer, use the previous conversion and convert it back to hexadecimal. This avoids the shift by $5$ problems while manipulating strings! Binary strings may be handled directly the way you indicated)